# Shabbat after losing track of time

Tags: halacha, shabbat, safek, chol-weekday

I have been reviewing the laws of what to do if one loses track of the days and doesn't know what day is shabbat. The laws are summarized [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=797). Is there any repercussion in terms of his life after he returns to civilization and discovers what day is actually shabbat? Has he elevated a wrong day in its kedusha to a point where he cannot lower the sanctity of it?

Comment: I don't get it. You think he might need to keep two shabbatot every week??

Comment: I don't know -- or make some change to the one day in acknowledgement that he elevated its status to some degree and lowering it would be wrong. This is why I ask.

Comment: As with most is X, questions, if the answer is no, one ends up needing to prove the negative which is very difficult...

Comment: shut harivash....

Comment: I think one can assume that in the case of an *ones*, one performs unusual actions in unusual circumstances. He has little or no other choice. That doesn't detract from his personal or spiritual status from failing to do the correct thing, which is what he should be doing once he returns to the normal situation. I'm not sure I follow the main concern of your question. Are you concerned that he may be punished for having sinned or done something incorrectly?

Comment: @DanF - no, that he elevated another day in terms of its kedusha and now that he returns, he cannot treat it like less than he elevated it. I wonder if I could even say that if he "observed it" a certain number of times it becomes tantamount to an accepted practice or a commitment on his part.

Comment: "tantamount to an accepted practice or a commitment on his part" - interesting question. Offhand, I don't think the rules of vows apply to cases of *ones*. Even if it did, one can have it annulled.